# Setting TOMCAT_HOME on Terminal. No such file or directory found

Tags: macos, terminal, environment-variables

export TOMCAT_HOME=”$(/usr/libexec/apache-tomcat-8.0.32)”

-bash: /usr/libexec/apache-tomcat-8.0.32: No such file or directory

Can you guide me please?

Comment: do you have tomcat 8.0.32 installed? is it in /usr/libexec?

Comment: Yes I have tomcat 8.0.32 installed already.

Comment: Just so you know JAVA_HOME is in the following                                   

Mymac-MacBook-Pro:~ mymac$ echo $JAVA_HOME

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home

Mymac-MacBook-Pro:~ mymac$

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the way the command is expressed:

```
export TOMCAT_HOME=”$(/usr/libexec/apache-tomcat-8.0.32)”
```

which is telling the shell to *evaluate* `/usr/libexec/apache-tomcat-8.0.32` (and set `TOMCAT_HOME` to the *result* of that evaluation).  That is probably a directory, and does not evaluate as an expression.  You should do something like this:

```
export TOMCAT_HOME=/usr/libexec/apache-tomcat-8.0.32
```

which merely uses the given *value* `/usr/libexec/apache-tomcat-8.0.32` without trying to make the value do something.

The `PATH` variable is a different case.  You might want to add the bin-directory of Tomcat to the path, e.g., by adding

```
export TOMCAT_HOME=/usr/libexec/apache-tomcat-8.0.32
export PATH=$TOMCAT_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

at the end of your `.profile` file (in your home directory).  When you start a (bash) shell in OSX, it initializes the `PATH` variable using the contents of `/etc/paths`.  Your `.profile` file can add to that.  (Other people may use `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, but you should read the manual page for `bash` to understand these alternatives).

Comment: Thank you. I was able to set TOMCAT_HOME. Now the next question is how to PERMANENTLY save it in PATH.